# How to check status code 200 or not using swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to validate my response status code is equal to 200 or not but == or != not working. Please give some sample.

```
JSON Response:{
    message = "registered Successfull";
    result =     {
        "created_by" = "2012-03-14 07:26:31";
        "created_ts" = "2013-03-14 07:26:31";
        "c_email" = "jk@mail.com";
        "c_lastname" = hi;
        "c_name" = sc;
        id = 123;
        login =         {
            authorization = z2VIownsD0Pr1jIMhJE;
        };
        "phone_no" = 123XXXX;
    };
    status = 1;
    "status_code" = 200;
}
```

My Code below

```
let status_code = result["status_code"]  as? [String: AnyObject]           
if (status_code! == "200") {
    print("ERROR:\(String(describing: status_code))")
} else {
    let results = result["result"]  as? [String: AnyObject]
    if let login = results!["login"]  as? [String: AnyObject] {
        let authorization = login["authorization"] as? String
        print(authorization ?? "")
    }
    self.navigatepop() // Not working
}
```

Comment: in this line let status_code = result["status_code"]  as? [String: AnyObject], from where you are getting the result? Please update some more code.

Comment: I mean your result property is holding complete response or just holding dictionary on result key.

Comment: So, you're trying to say, `status_code` is a dictionary, using `let status_code = result["status_code"]  as? [String: AnyObject]`, which makes `if (status_code! == "200") {` ... um, wrong.  I would then think, based on your example json, something like `let status_code = result["status_code"]  as? Int` would be more accurate

Comment: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964975/checking-http-status-swift4/50965108#50965108)[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50964975/checking-http-status-swift4/50965108#50965108]

Comment: see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38371870/operator-in-swift/46504728#46504728

Answer (score 1):

You can try if **status_code** is in `String`

```
if let json = response.result.value as? [String: Any] {
  let status_code : String = json["status_code"]! as! String 
    // here you can check if it is in Integer format
    if(status_code == "200") {
      //Your code after success code
      }
}
```

Comment: simple and easy but if use `?`  at the place of this `!` it work well.

Comment: `let status_code : Int = json["status_code"]! as! Int` You can use if in `Int`

Answer (score 0):

```
 if let json = response.result.value{
    let responseDict = json as! NSDictionary
    if let statusCode = responseDict.object(forKey: "status_code") as? Int {
        print(statusCode)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In json: `"status_code" = 200;`  status_code is Int value, so you must to unswapping

```
let status_code = result["status_code"]  as?  Int{   // not as? [String: AnyObject]  or can : as? String
```

And `if (status_code! == "200") {` is  `status_code == 200`  Or `status_code == "200"`

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting value in this `result["status_code"]`

then remove this

```
let status_code = result["status_code"]  as? [String: AnyObject]
```

to

```
let status_code = result["status_code"]  as? [String] // or any other [datatypes]
```

may be it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
if let jsonDictionary = response.result.value as? [String: Any], let status_code : Int = jsonDictionary["status_code"] as? Int {

        if(status_code == 200) {
            //Your success code
         if  let results = jsonDictionary["result"]  as? [String: AnyObject], let login = results["login"]  as? [String: AnyObject] , let authorization = login["authorization"] as? String {
                     print(authorization )
         } else {
             self.navigatepop() // status_code == 200 but 
         }
    } else {
             // your else code , status_code != 200
        }
    }
```